# Can the gcc C preprocessor use the output of a shell command?

Tags: c, shell, gcc, c-preprocessor

For example, can the output of 'uname -a' be used to create the COMPILED_ON macro below?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COMPILED_ON `call uname -a and use the output as a quoted string'

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    printf( COMPILED_ON );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

no, but:

```
gcc -DCOMPILED_ON="$(uname -a)"
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that you can do that with the GNU preprocessor, but surely it's not doable with a plain standard preprocessor; instead, I think that this is the job for the Makefile.

Let it run `uname -a` and store it in a Makefile variable, that will be used to create the correct `-D` directive for the compiler.

You could also make the Makefile create a `.h` file that will contain the macro definition, and that file will be `#include`d by the files that need the `COMPILED_ON` macro. This has the extra bonus of being independent of compiler-specific options to define macros.

Notice that these suggestions are applicable also to build tools other than the good ol' make.

Answer (score 3):

Not like that, no.

You'd need to do:

```
gcc "-DCOMPILED_ON=\"`uname -a`\"" -c file.c -o file.o
```

Alternatively, have your makefile create a simple .h file:

```
echo "#define COMPILED_ON \"`uname -a`\"" > compiledon.h
```

Then `#include "compiledon.h"`

You'll need the `\"` part in order to get a usable string.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can achieve your objective in a less fragile and SCCS-hostile manner.

1. Have a make target run a shell script to create a `.h` file.
2. Have a make variable set itself via a shell command and pass down a `-D`. Not all `make(1)` implementations support this.
3. Have your make target run the compiler with a -D that incorporates the shell command.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use CMake I have a nice snippet that might help some:

```
# This ensures the SHA1 git ref is shown within the app
execute_process(COMMAND git rev-parse HEAD WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} OUTPUT_VARIABLE GITSHA1REF)
string(REGEX REPLACE "\n$" "" GITSHA1REF "${GITSHA1REF}")
message(STATUS "GITSHA1REF = ${GITSHA1REF}")
add_definitions("-DGITSHA1REF=\"${GITSHA1REF}\"")
```

With that I get the current Git SHA1 hash and use it like this in my C++ code:

```
std::cout << "Git-SHA1: " << GITSHA1REF << std::endl;
```